# AttributeError: type object 'Page' has no attribute 'query'

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

Trying to add a custom batch action but I keep getting this error, I've added my imports into the code to show what i'm importing, this file is separate to my model file, this is my views.py file

**Views.py**

```
import flask_admin as admin
import textwrap
from flask_admin.actions import action
from flask_admin.contrib import sqla
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla.filters import FilterEqual
from app.models import FileRegister, FileRegisterStatus
from app import app, db, models


class PageView(ModelView):
    @action("active", "Active", 'Are you sure you want to active selected pages?')
def action_active(self, ids):
    try:
        query = Page.query.filter(Page.id.in_(ids))

        count = 0
        for page in query.all():
            page.is_active = True    
            count += 1

        flash(ngettext('Page was successfully activated.',
                       '%(count)s pages were successfully activated.',
                       count,
                       count=count))
    except Exception as ex:
        if not self.handle_view_exception(ex):
            raise

        flash(gettext('Failed to active pages. %(error)s', error=str(ex)), 'error')
```

**models.py**

```
    from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Boolean, TIMESTAMP, ForeignKey
import datetime

Base = declarative_base()


class Page(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'page'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False, autoincrement=True)
    page_name= Column(String(500), index=True, nullable=False)
    is_page_active= Column(Boolean())

    def __init__(self, page_name, is_page_active):
        self.page_name= page_name
        self.is_page_active= is_page_active

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.page_name
```

This is the Traceback (most recent call last) I get after running the code, ,I think its because I call query() on my mapped classes instead of the session?

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\page\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\page\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\page\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\page\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\page\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\page\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\page\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\page\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\page\flask_admin\base.py", line 69, in inner
    return self._run_view(f, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\page\flask_admin\base.py", line 368, in _run_view
    return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\page\flask_admin\model\base.py", line 2145, in action_view
    return self.handle_action()
  File "C:\page\flask_admin\actions.py", line 117, in handle_action
    response = handler[0](ids)
  File "C:\page\app\views.py", line 28, in action_active
    if not self.handle_view_exception(ex):
  File "c:\page\flask_admin\contrib\sqla\view.py", line 1060, in handle_view_exception
    return super(ModelView, self).handle_view_exception(exc)
  File "C:\page\app\views.py", line 16, in action_active
    query = Page.query.filter(Page.active_ind.in_(ids))
AttributeError: type object 'Page' has no attribute 'query'
```

Comment: With no knowledge of the classes/packages being used, try `query = Page.query().filter(Page.id.in_(ids))`?

Comment: @RobMurray I've added my packages, I use a page model in my model class

Comment: I believe since you are using the declarative model, you want to create a session object and execute queries on that based on the model. Something along of the lines of `session.query(Page).filter_by(Page.id.in_(ids))`. Check out the section [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#adding-and-updating-objects) on the SQLAlchemy page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I was using a declarative model, this was the fix. This goes into the models.py file

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker    

engine = create_engine('databaselinkgoeshere', convert_unicode=True)
    db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                             autoflush=False,
                                             bind=engine))

Base = declarative_base()
Base.query = db_session.query_property()
```